# How to get timestamp as Unix epoch from postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, epoch

I want to get data from Postgres. There is a column in type timestamp without timezone. Simple SELECT returns me formatted date but I want timestamp in miliseconds simply. How I can do it in SQL?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
select extract(epoch from my_timestamp)
```

This returns time in seconds. However, it is a decimal number with fractions of the second after the decimal point. Read more about precision below.

For millis, use:

```
select extract(epoch from my_timestamp)*1000
```

Test:

```
select my_date, 
extract(epoch from my_date)*interval'1s'+'epoch'::timestamp at time zone 'GMT'
```

**Note on precision**

`extract` returns a "double precision" number, which fits 15 digits in Postgres. It means that around 2016 (as I write this), the actual precision is 10 microseconds. Note how it rounds off the last digit:

```
select extract('epoch' from '2016-09-20T11:22:33.456789Z'::timestamp);
    date_part     
------------------
 1474370553.45679
(1 row)
```

For dates like 270 years in the future, this data type will only be able to represent 100-microsecond precision. Seems like a decent precision from the perspective of 2016, and I guess things might change a bit before we reach that year.

```
select extract('epoch' from '2290-09-20T11:22:33.456789Z'::timestamp);
    date_part     
------------------
 10120936953.4568
(1 row)
```

Either way, it will continue to work just fine for *millisecond* precision for a while.

Comment: This suggesstion does not help if you need a millisecond-precision

Comment: @Wiebke It does. See if the updated answer explains it better.

Answer (score 2):

If you are only interested in the seconds, use the trunc function around it:

```
select trunc(extract(epoch from now() )* 1000);
```